# ComponentScan Flow in spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have annotation Component Scan in the `main class App.java` and I have annotation Component in **four** classes

**example**: `A.java`, `B.Java`, `C.java` and `D.java` with  annotation  Component in different Packages.

Here how the application will know to go to `C.Java` first.I did not mentioned any packages at annotation Component Scan in the `main class`,But when I run the application i can see it is going to `C.java` first.Can you please explain how?
 I'm running as java run as application.I just want to  know the concept of annotation Component when  we are not mentioning base packages in  the main the class.

Answer (score 1):

Then your spring-boot application is annotated with The `@SpringBootApplication`.

`@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using `@Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration and @ComponentScan` with their default attributes.

One more point if you didn;t specify the base package name in `@ComponentScan`,
it will scan from the package, where the `@Springbootapplication` present.

For more infor, [Spring-Boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html)

Answer (score 0):

@ComponentScan Java doc states that

> If specific packages are not defined, scanning will occur from the
>   package of the class that declares this annotation.

That is probably the reason why your Class C is being scanned.

[Spring Java Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)